# Output to specific areas of a file to another file using awk or sed?

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

I have a file that looks like this:

```
d "Text 1":6,64;1 /filesys1/db1.d2
d "Text 2":6,64;1 /filesys1/db1.d2 f 730
d "Text 3":6,64;1 /filesys1/db1.d2 
d "TextA":6,64;1 /filesys1/db1.d2 f 46000
d "TextB":6,64;1 /filesys1/db1.d2
d "TextC":6,64;1 /filesys1/db1.d2 f 120000
...
```

I need to get everything from between the quotes and then the last 2 characters of the line and put it in a new file.  I can do the two pieces separately but I can't combine them and get it to work.

```
awk -F'"' '$0=$2' datatmp4 > dataout2
```

will get me:

```
Text 1
Text 2
Text 3
TextA
TextB
TextC
```

and

```
awk '{ print substr( $NF, length($NF) -1, length($NF) ) }' datatmp4 > dataout
```

will get me:

```
d2
30
d2
00
d2
00
```

what I need is:

```
Text 1 d2
Text 2 30
Text 3 d2
TextA 00
TextB d2
TextC 00
```

Answer (score 3):

You could concatenate the result using $2 for the text between quotes along with the result from the last 2 characters as below:

```
awk -F '"' '{print $2, substr($NF, length($NF)-1, length($NF))}' datatmp4 > dataout
```

Comment: You don;t need that 3rd arg to substr() - printing to the end of the string passed as the first arg is the default behavior.

Answer (score 3):

You're making things too hard on yourself. There's no reason to care about or try to operate on the last field on the line ($NF) when all you want is the last 2 characters of the whole line:

```
$ awk -F'"' '{print $2, substr($0,length()-1)}' file
Text 1 d2
Text 2 30
Text 3 2
TextA 00
TextB d2
TextC 00
```

The third line of output ends in `2<blank>` because that's what was in your input file. That doesn't match your posted desired output though so be clear - do you want the last chars of each line as I've shown and you said you wanted, or do you want the last 2 non-blank chars as implied by your posted desired output?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F"\"" '{match($NF,/..$/,a); print $2,a[0]}' last2
Text 1 d2
Text 2 30
Text 3 2
TextA 00
TextB d2
TextC 00
```

Comment: The last character on one of lines is a space, dunno if it's a typo but it will break this answer.

Comment: right, length based substr selection will do the same.

Comment: Nope because you have defined a different `FS`, OP's ignores the last spaces due to default `FS`, although the answer they said worked great uses `"` so dunno actually

Comment: You should state that's gawk-specific for the 3rd arg to match().

Answer (score -1):

With sed (BRE):

```
sed 's/^[^"]*"\([^"]*\).*\(.[^ ]\)/\1 \2/;' file
```

Another way with sed (ERE):

```
sed -E 's/^[^"]*"|"[^ ]*( ).*(.[^ ])/\1\2/g' file
```

With awk:

```
awk -F'"' '{ print $2 " " gensub(/.*(.[^ ])/, "\\1", 1)}' file
```

The field separator is a quote. `gensub` replaces all characters from line except the 2 last characters (the second must not be a space).

Comment: You've got the gensub() args wrong. What you are doing now will use `$4` as the count of how many times to perform the substitution, and it will operate on the default $0 since the 4th arg is missing. Assuming you're trying to do something one time with $4 it'd be `gensub(/.*(..)/, "\\1", 1, $4)` but there are only 3 `"`-separated fields in the OPs example so that wouldn't work anyway. Also, instead of `print $2 " " gensub...` you should just let the OFS do it's job: `print $2, gensub...`. I didn't downvote it btw.

Comment: @EdMorton: you are right, it's the field 3 and the target parameter is not needed at all. Note that strangely `gensub(/.*([^ ]{2})/, "\\1", $4)` returns the good result (even if it is false).

Comment: `gensub(/.*([^ ]{2})/, "\\1", $4)` produces the expected output because gawk interprets it as `gensub(/.*([^ ]{2})/, "\\1", $4, $0)` so it sees the value of `$4` as the 3rg arg and so if `$4` starts with g/G then gensub will do a global substitution, and if `$4` is a number N then gensub will do the substitution on the Nth occurrence of the regexp, and if `$4` is anything else then gawk will treat it as a `1` and do the substitution on the 1st occurrence of the regexp. In this case `$4` is always `NULL` so treated as `1` so it's equivalent to the desired `gensub(/.*([^ ]{2})/, "\\1", 1)`